# im trying to make auto role in discord.js and its not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
  bot.on('GuildMerberadd' , member => {
    console.log('User' + member.user.username + 'Has Joined the server!')

    var role = member.guild.role.find('name,' , 'user');
    member.addrole(Members)
 }
```

The console logged the follwing error: **Unexpected identifier**
Please help me!

Comment: you need to explain your problem little bit more and with more code please refer for more help on this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The `GuildMerberadd` event doesn't exist, you have to use [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd).
The second mistake is that Guild has the `.roles` property and not `.role`.
More information [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild).

I fixed your errors and with this code it should work:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  console.log('User' + member.user.tag + 'has joined the server!');

  var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'user');
  member.addRole(role);
}
```

Comment: `member.addrole(role)` should be [`member.addRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole)